# In VsCode, how do I get rid of the air to the right of the text?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I cannot use the full width of the panel in VsCode.

As can be seen in the picture it is quite a lot of space I can't use. (the red line)
Which setting should I change?

I do not have that many extensions and I have not played around very much in the settings either. (I set [up a new machine every 30 och 90 days](https://www.selfelected.com/experimenting-with-setting-up-a-new-machine-every-third-month/) and hence don't fiddle around too much.)

[image]

Here are my relevant settings:

```
"editor.lineNumbers": "off",
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 100,
"editor.wordWrap": "on",
"editor.minimap.enabled": false,
```

The word wrap is at 80 characters which also happens to be the standard `editor.wordWrapColumn` but I am not using it but have `editor.ordWrap` set to `on`. (`on` means word wrap but not at a special column count)
I have set `editor.wordWrapColumn` to another value but, as supposed, nothing changes as long as I have `etidor.wordWrap` set to `on`.
I have played with setting `editor.wordWrapColumn` to, say, 100 and `editor.wordWrap` to `wordWrapColumn` which, as supposed, makes the lines break at 100. Setting it back and everything goes back to (ab)normal.

Comment: You have line wrap enabled. If you go to "View / Render Whitespace", what do you see?

Comment: There are no white spaces. I have word wrap enabled but set to `on` (and not `wordWrapColumn` or `bounded`)

Comment: There is still the same issues one year later. Maybe we could create an github issue? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=white+space+word+wrap+right+

Answer (score 0):

That is just space so your lines can grow longer. Basically to remove it resize your window to the desired space. (In case you mean the minimap just go into settings and disable it)

Comment: The lines can't grow longer. Line 136 breaks at `'%'`.

Comment: Sorry didn't see that, could you try disabling the minimap?

Comment: Good idea. Tried it already, turning it on/off/on/off. I updated my Q with the info.